# How do i Count based on multiple Conditions

Tags: sql, select, sql-server-2008-r2, counter

I have current 4 Columns `Id`, `A`, `B` and `C`

```
 A     B    C
243    3    1
243    3    2
243    3    3
243    3    1
243    3    2
243    3    3
243    3    1
243    3    2
243    3    3
185    3    1
185    3    2
185    3    3
185    3    1
185    3    2
185    3    3
337    2    1
337    2    2
337    2    3
337    2    4
337    2    5
337    2    1
337    2    2
337    2    3
337    2    4
337    2    5
336    2    1
336    2    2
336    2    3
336    2    4
336    2    5
```

Logic

- When current C is **<** previous C then count **+1**
- But When current A **<>** previous A then **reset** count

the result would look like

```
 A     B    C  count
243    3    1    0
243    3    2    0
243    3    3    0
243    3    1    1
243    3    2    1
243    3    3    1
243    3    1    2
243    3    2    2
243    3    3    2
185    3    1    0
185    3    2    0
185    3    3    0
185    3    1    1
185    3    2    1
185    3    3    1
337    2    1    0
337    2    2    0
337    2    3    0
337    2    4    0
337    2    5    0
337    2    1    1
337    2    2    1
337    2    3    1
337    2    4    1
337    2    5    1
336    2    1    0
336    2    2    0
336    2    3    0
336    2    4    0
336    2    5    0
```

It would also be possible to use Column B to know the max of C

- if B == 3  C max will be 3
- if B == 2  C max will be 5

my Current try is

```
SELECT *, 
       1 + ((row_number() over(order by A, B, Id, C) - 1) / 
Case  B    WHEN 2 THEN 5
           ELSE 3 END)
 AS Test
```

Which will do part 1

> When current C is **<** previous C then count **+1**

But not part2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible solution that will work in SQL Server 2008 (without `LEAD`/`LAG`). The main idea is to use `PARTITION BY A` to "reset" the counter.
Result set has intermediate columns, so you can follow the logic. It is pretty straight-forward.

**Sample data**

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (ID int IDENTITY(1,1), [A] int, [B] int, [C] int);

INSERT INTO @T ([A], [B], [C])
VALUES
    (243, 3, 1),
    (243, 3, 2),
    (243, 3, 3),
    (243, 3, 1),
    (243, 3, 2),
    (243, 3, 3),
    (243, 3, 1),
    (243, 3, 2),
    (243, 3, 3),
    (185, 3, 1),
    (185, 3, 2),
    (185, 3, 3),
    (185, 3, 1),
    (185, 3, 2),
    (185, 3, 3),
    (337, 2, 1),
    (337, 2, 2),
    (337, 2, 3),
    (337, 2, 4),
    (337, 2, 5),
    (337, 2, 1),
    (337, 2, 2),
    (337, 2, 3),
    (337, 2, 4),
    (337, 2, 5),
    (336, 2, 1),
    (336, 2, 2),
    (336, 2, 3),
    (336, 2, 4),
    (336, 2, 5);
```

**Query**

```
WITH
CTE_Test
AS
(
    SELECT
        ID, A, B, C,
        1 + ((row_number() over(order by A, B, Id, C) - 1) / 
        Case B WHEN 2 THEN 5 ELSE 3 END) AS Test
    FROM @T
)
,CTE_Min
AS
(
    SELECT
        ID, A, B, C, Test
        , MIN(Test) OVER(PARTITION BY A) AS MinTest
    FROM CTE_Test
)
SELECT
    ID, A, B, C, Test, MinTest
    , Test - MinTest AS FinalCount
FROM CTE_Min
ORDER BY ID;
```

**Result set**

```
ID    A      B    C    Test    MinTest    FinalCount
1     243    3    1    3       3          0
2     243    3    2    3       3          0
3     243    3    3    3       3          0
4     243    3    1    4       3          1
5     243    3    2    4       3          1
6     243    3    3    4       3          1
7     243    3    1    5       3          2
8     243    3    2    5       3          2
9     243    3    3    5       3          2
10    185    3    1    1       1          0
11    185    3    2    1       1          0
12    185    3    3    1       1          0
13    185    3    1    2       1          1
14    185    3    2    2       1          1
15    185    3    3    2       1          1
16    337    2    1    5       5          0
17    337    2    2    5       5          0
18    337    2    3    5       5          0
19    337    2    4    5       5          0
20    337    2    5    5       5          0
21    337    2    1    6       5          1
22    337    2    2    6       5          1
23    337    2    3    6       5          1
24    337    2    4    6       5          1
25    337    2    5    6       5          1
26    336    2    1    4       4          0
27    336    2    2    4       4          0
28    336    2    3    4       4          0
29    336    2    4    4       4          0
30    336    2    5    4       4          0
```